# Is there a way to "lock" the proportions of an photoshop file so the end user cannot change them?

Tags: export

I am creating ad files for concert events and the end users (think church bulletin - no offense intended) are always stretching the files to meet a space, creating a horizontal or vertical squash that renders it almost unreadable. 
It would be great to lock the proportion so they can change it.

Comment: I think you have to do is tell the end user: Do not stretch the file.

Comment: One theoretical way exists. They get your image as installable software which locks their system to otherwise normal, but your image is never embedded, stays in proportions and  it's only a cloud link (not readable in normal ways) even in the PDF. This is not practical because you must feed something which can be seen as system wide malware. Generating it needs top notch programming capablities, opens easily a door to the jail and collects high compensation claims. Try some friendly negotiations.

Comment: Perhaps you need to design to more common reproduction sizes? just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

No nothing on my computer is such that I can not change it. So once you give the file out to somebody they can change it, period. If nothing else they can take a screenshot of your work and edit that. If its on your server than at least you can reject me but whatever you sent me i can change.

However your looking at this the wrong way, you dont really need to have a enforcement scheme. Your working with these people not despite or against them. Ask nicely. Hey i have reserved this slot for you could you insert your stuff into it, these are the limitations becasue of such and such.

PS: are you sure you dont want to use inDesign?

Comment: Thank you, everyone. As in most volunteer situations, the person putting together the bulletin is experienced only in rudimentary desktop publishing. The materials were presented in a typical 1 column width, but she finds a way to mash it down. I have taken the nice route a number of times to no avail. I appreciate knowing I haven't missed something.